# C# oncheckedchanged event handler of aspcheckbox does not fire when checkbox is unc

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey could you look at this code: I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.   Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
{
    CheckBox chkBox1 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[8].FindControl("chkStatus"); 
    chkBox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged); 
    chkBox1.Checked = true; 
    chkBox1.AutoPostBack = true;
}
```

Comment: i mean i add this handler in GridView2RowDataBound

Comment: Please use the *edit* button below the post to edit the post

Comment: 0
 
down vote 
accept  thanks. not sure that in M_Y first line, the FindControl method call is actually returning a control. WHy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, check your cell count and check if there is a CheckBox at the control referenced by FindControl.

```
if (e.Row.Cells.Count > 8)
{
  CheckBox chkBox1 = e.Row.Cells[8].FindControl("chkStatus") as CheckBox;

  if (chkBox1 != null)
  { 
    chkBox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged); 
    chkBox1.Checked = true; 
    chkBox1.AutoPostBack = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: i tryed use Count array (for int i = 0; i <e.Row.Cells.Count)

Comment: but it's ok. When i try to assign some value like Checked it returns Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: How can i detect if chkBox1 is Null? In See SHarp i use like it: CheckBox box1 = (CheckBox) e.Row.Cells[8].FindControl("chkStatus");

Comment: It worked but Handler in CheckedChanged not working as the same. What should i do? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that in your first line, the FindControl method call is actually returning a control. Try putting a  breakpoint on line 166 and see what chkBox1 is equal to at that point. My guess is that its value is  null.

Comment: It worked but Handler in CheckedChanged not working as the same. What should i do? Thanks

Comment: When you say it worked...what exactly worked? You are getting a control back now? And what do you mean by the Handler is not working the same. Working the same was what? How is it not working? In order to better assist you, we need more information.

Comment: It worked I mean I can assign Checked Value and Handler value with += BUT! It was'not reacting for this handler. I tried to put Response.Write in that code of handler... and no result. Pitty. :(